# how do you invoke a browse to url in netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

is there a short-cut command to browse to a file in Netbeans for instance:

```
  <a href=" how do i browse to a file from here  ">
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file belongs to your project and the path is valid then you just have to hold `Ctrl` and click on the link (it will be underlined when you hold `Ctrl`).

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear , I mean how do you browse to the file to insert into the code , so place curser inside  <a href=" "> and then browse to the file/path you want to insert ? many thanks

Comment: You want Netbean to show you the possible path/file you can use in the href? If so between `" "` press `Ctrl+Space`